# What are the $x$ intercepts of the equation $f(x)=-3(x+7)^4+48$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

What are the $x$ intercepts of the equation $f(x)=-3(x+7)^4+48$?

I know that I need to make $f(x)=0$ then solve for $x$, but how would I solve for the quartic?

Comment: Don't forget to accept an answer for the factoring question: solve for k. How'd it work out with yesterday's question? Where you had to solve for a and b?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set $f(x) = 0$.
You have $$3(x-7)^4 = 48.$$
Divide by 3 to get
$$(x-7)^4 = 16.$$
Now extract a square root, twice, to obtain
$$x - 7 = \pm 2.$$
I think you can do the rest.  You might get more solutions in the complex realm.

Comment: ok thanks, i think i thought about it too much

Comment: In general, equate it zero, re arrange the term and try out various algebaric formulas to solver for $x$

Comment: @jasminder88 Please accept the answer once you are satisfied with the solution.